# what is wrong with if-then-else here?

Tags: haskell

I have tried this in multiple ways: if-then-else, guards, case statements but I never manage to get it compiled. I think from the code it is quite clear what I want to do. Why is this not possible and what must I do to get it straight?

```
appendMsg :: String -> (String, Integer) -> Map.Map (String, Integer) [String] -> Map.Map (String, Integer) [String]
appendMsg  a (b,c) m = do
      let Just le1 = length . concat <$> Map.lookup (b,c) m
          le2 = le1 + length a
      if le2 < 1400 then (let m2 = Map.adjust (x ++ [a]) (b, c) m) else (print (le1, le2))
      return (m2)
```

The error message I get here is `` parse error on input `)' ``. If I change the brackets I get `` parse error on input `else' ``. If I say in the else path (let m2 = m) then I get again the bracket error.

What I try to achieve is, if le2 <= 1400 then m2 should be created by using

```
f x = x ++ [a]
m2 = Map.adjust f (b, c) m
```

if le2 > 1400 then an other function should be called that takes the same arguments than appendMsg and appendMsg should simply return nothing.

An additional problem is that as soon as this is set right according to all recommendations below:

`if le2 < 1400 then let m2 = Map.adjust (++ [a]) (b, c) m in return (m2) else return ()`

I get an error saying

```
 No instance for (Monad (Map.Map (String, Integer)))
      arising from a use of `return'
```

That is by the way the same error I eventually got when I used guards. The problem is that there is little I can do in the remaining code with this strange type. Can I convert this type then in any way back to (Map.Map (String, Integer) [String]) or avoid it altogether?

Comment: Generally it's considered a good idea to include what error message you're getting.

Comment: What's `m2` equal to if `le2 >= 1400`?

Comment: What do you return if the `else` path is followed?

Comment: On the specific example I get 'parse error on input `)'' if I change the brackets I get 'arse error on input `else'' if I use guards it either complains about the type (monad) or that a do block must end with an expression. All not really meaningful I think.

Comment: Both branches of your `if-then-else` statement must have the same type. The `then` branch of your statement doesn't actually have a type at all, since you have a let-binding without any followup statements, and the `else` branch is actually of type `IO ()`, which doesn't work in your function.

Comment: If Haskell is reporting an 'arse error', I'd say it was being cheeky (sorry, British joke).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `do`, whose result must be a `Monad` instance, but your function's type indicates that it returns a `Map` which is not an instance of `Monad`.  If you really want to return `Nothing` when `le2 >= 1400`, then you will have to return `Just ...` when `le2 < 1400`, and your function could look like this:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Monad

appendMsg :: String -> (String, Integer) ->
             Map.Map (String, Integer) [String] ->
             Maybe (Map.Map (String, Integer) [String])
appendMsg  a k m = do
      v <- Map.lookup k m
      let l = length . concat $ v 
          l' = l + length a
      guard $ l' < 1400
      return $ Map.insert k (v ++ a) m
```

Note that this function will return `Nothing` if it can't find the key in the `Map` to begin with...

Comment: The $ here would abbreviate () ?

Comment: `$` is a lower-precedence form of function application.  `f a $ g b` is equivalent to `f a (g b)`.  It's mostly for eliminating parens, but is also useful when you want to treat function application as a function (like `map ($ a) fs` which applies each function in `fs` to the argument `a`, and returns the results as a list).

Comment: Can the problem with the Monad instance really be the 'do'? Can this not be related to the use of 'guard' and MonadPlus?

Comment: Sort of.  You can do `x = do 3`, and it works, even though `3` is not an instance of `Monad`.  However, if you have two 'statements' in the `do`, they will be connected by `>>=` (or `>>`) which will require them both to be the same `Monad` instance.

Answer (score 4):

`let` must either be followed by `in` or be directly inside a `do` block. `let` must not be the last statement in a `do` block. These rules are a consequence of the fact that it makes no sense to create a variable that goes out of scope immediately without any chance of being used.

In your code you create a variable called `m2` inside the `then` branch of the `if`, but you never use it. You do (try to) use it outside the `if`, but outside the `if` `m2` doesn't exist. You can't use a variable that's been created inside an `if` outside of that `if`. What should the value of `m2` be when the `if` condition was false?

Comment: In case le2 <= 1400 I want to create the local variable m2.

Comment: @JFritsch: Your code is always returning `m2`. What are you expecting to happen if `le2 > 1400`?

Comment: @KevinBallard In this case I want to call an other function that flushes my queue. The print is dummy code only.

Comment: @JFritsch The point is that the variable only exists inside the `then`-branch. If you put the `return` inside the `then`-branch (and do something well-typed in the `else`-branch), it'll work.

Comment: @sepp2k Understand now. But how could I achieve what I need to do: if le2 <= 1400 create m2 and return that?

Comment: @JFritsch By putting the `return` inside the `then`-branch. I.e. `if foo then let m2 = bar in return m2` or simply `if foo then return bar`. Of course you still have the problem that the `else` branch must return something of the same type, which it does not in your code sample.

Comment: @sepp2k works. Thanks. Now it complains about my function (x ++ [a]) that should actually be f x = x ++ [a], but there seemed no way to bring that in.

Comment: The way to fix that is to use `(++ [a])`, which is called a section.  (That's equivalent to `\ x -> x ++ [a]`.)